# Having problems printing åäö (├Ñ ├à | ├ñ ├ä | ├Â ├û)

Tags: c, utf-8

I can't print the swedish letters åäö.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
   printf("å Å | ä Ä | ö Ö");

   return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

> ├Ñ ├à | ├ñ ├ä | ├Â ├û

I don't understand what is wrong. I've searched google and stackoverflow, but nothing to be found. Maybe there is something wrong with UTF-8?

Other information that might be usefull:

I'm using Windows 10 and atom.

**SOLUTION**

Go to:

***System language settings -> Administrative language settings -> Change system 
 locale...***

Now check the following box:

**[Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support]**

This fixed my problem and I am now able to use UTF-8 characters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1421811/11683? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50658001/11683?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with utf-8, there is only something wrong with Windows. As far as I know, the windows terminal does not support utf-8. At least it didn't the last time I used it. I have heard some rumors that Microsoft was going to add support, but I don't think it has happened yet. If you are going to write terminal applications I only see four courses of actions: 1. wait for utf-8 support. 2. Wrangle with different extended ascii codepages or utf-16 3. Stick to 7 bit us-ascii 4. get a real os.

Comment: I am assuming you can't change encodings, Unicode might be a better choice.  Windows has always been a mess when it came to encodings, but from what I remember, it has full support for unicode

Comment: Changing the language settings to Beta/UTF8 will break old ANSI programs, if you have any of them on your system. You should just use `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)` as suggested in the answer below, or use UTF16 which is the recommended method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows command window (terminal, console, whatever you call it) *does* support UTF-8 since several years, at least with Windows 7 based on my experiences. You need to set the code page:

```
mode con cp select=65001
```

Additionally you can set the output code page programmatically:

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your suggestion was great, it didn't work for me, though it did set me on the right path towards the correct solution.  

My solution was to do the following: 

   System language settings -> Administrative language settings -> Change system locale... 

   Now check the following box:

      [Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support]

This fixed my problem and I am now able to use UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Would you mind to tell us, how did it not work for you? Did you set a font with a big "enough" character set, for example?

Comment: Also change to `printf(u8"å Å | ä Ä | ö Ö")` and make sure your *.c file is saved in Unicode format.